# Displaying form on codition codename one

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, codenameone

I am developing a application in codename one that required a user to login.
I created a login form and a main form.
I want to add a functionality that if the user is already logged in. main form will show.
The function check if the app has a preference token of username with some value.
it open main form 
if the token does not have a value the login form will appear.

i need help to know how to open forms designed in GUI Builder
to be called in code.

If you are experiencing an issue please mention the full platform your issue applies to:
IDE: NetBeans/Eclipse/IDEA:IDEA
Desktop OS:Ubuntu
Simulator:Default
Device:ANDROID

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at [this](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html).

From code you can just do `showForm("MyFormName", null);`

Comment: Where to use this code. I think this function is protected.

Comment: I want to use `Preferences.get("username","DEFAULT");`

Comment: If it get DEFAULT then my `LoginForm` appear else `Main`

Comment: You can use that code within the statemachine. It is public.

Comment: I did it by hard-coding it in staticmachinebase class where it check for the name of inital form.

Comment: No you need to select the form, select events, click the "before show" button and write the code there (the IDE will create a method in the state machine class). Never edit the state machine base